# Tumblr Captions

Tags: html, tumblr

Question about tumblr coding. Is it possible to go into the HTML of a given theme and insert a caption that will appear on every photo/video/audio/text post? This includes old posts as well as future posts.

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried so far to debug easily

Comment: Do you mean a fixed text (for all posts the same)?

Comment: Yes, the same text/caption for every post, past and future.

Comment: If it's the same text, this is easy you can simply add something like <p>Fixed text content</p> inside the {Post} blocks in the template. This content is not indexed though ASFAIK, so it wont affect SEO.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally got the command in the right places, and it works!

Answer (score 2):

I thought it might be useful to add a detailed answer in case anyone is interested to see some code examples. Specifically for photo posts since this is a useful one.

Using the default Optica theme as an example (other themes will differ, but this is a good overview), the different post types (text/photo/etc) are rendered within the {block:Posts} tags.

```
{block:Posts}
     ... lots of code to render all the different post types is in here...
{/block:Posts}
```

For photo posts (you can do something similar for the other post types as you desire), if you want to add some caption text below each photo on your page you can add text inside the {block:Caption} tags (see * * *):

```
{block:Photo}
    <figure class="post-content {block:HighRes}high-res{/block:HighRes}{block:Caption} with-caption{/block:Caption}" data-photo-width="{PhotoWidth-HighRes}">
        <div class="photo-wrapper">
            <div class="photo-wrapper-inner">
                {LinkOpenTag}
                   <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="{PhotoWidth-HighRes}" height="{PhotoHeight-HighRes}">
                {LinkCloseTag}
             </div>
         </div>

         {block:Caption}
             <figcaption class="caption">
                 <!--{Caption}-->

                 * * * Hello, this is my new caption text * * *
             </figcaption>
         {/block:Caption}
     </figure>
{/block:Photo}
```

You can also hide any existing caption text that the post author may have added by commenting out the {caption} line as I have shown in the example above.

Alternatively, if you do want the caption to appear on every post type no matter what, you can experiment with placing the text just above the closing {/block:Posts} tag and then moving it up into different div sections until it sits where you want it.